# Autoplay is removed from HTML after rendering

Tags: reactjs, video

I am implementing HTML in react to generate and facing a problem with video `autoplay`
this is how my file looks like

**home.js**

```
import video_two from './../images/tab-sidebar.mp4';

class Noticias extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <video autoplay muted loop class="hide-tablet video-2">
        <source src={video_two} type="video/mp4" />
        <p>Joykal Infotech</p>
      </video>
    )
  }
}
```

**generated HTML**

```
<video loop="" class="hide-tablet">
  <source src="/static/media/noticias-full-website-scroll.069654da.webm" type="video/webm">
  <p>Joykal Infotech</p>
</video>
```

I don't understand why and how the `autoplay` and `muted` are removed from the `video` tag. Suggestions are appreciated

## Update

Figured it myself the react is camelcase sensitive and it supports `autoPlay` rather than `autoplay`.

Comment: You can answer your own question (+ accept your own answer), that way less people will miss the solution

Answer (score 0):

React is camelcase sensitive so you should use `autoPlay` instead of `autoplay`
like this:

```
<video autoPlay muted loop class="hide-tablet video-2">
  <source src={video_two} type="video/mp4" />
  <p>Joykal Infotech</p>
</video>
```